# How do you write a Pulumi provider that makes a REST API request in pytyon?

Tags: python, pulumi

I am attempting to write a Pulumi provider that automates creating resources in Fivetran. I've started with the user object, attempting to call the invite user API. Upon executing `pulumi up`, I receive the following errors:

```
Diagnostics:
  pulumi:pulumi:Stack (data-services-account-dev):
    C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\grpc\_server.py:448: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'invoke.<locals>.do_rpc' was never awaited
      return None, False
    RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

    error: update failed

  pulumi-python:dynamic:Resource (dev-slack-bot):
    error: Exception calling application: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'.

Resources:
    1 unchanged
```

I'm using the python requests library to make the API call to Fivetran and it is the `request.post` call that appears to trigger the exception.

Here is the code in fivetran_pulumi.py:

```
from pulumi import ComponentResource, export, Input, Output
from pulumi.dynamic import Resource, ResourceProvider, CreateResult
from typing import Optional

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

class FivetranUserArgs(object):
  given_name: Input[str]
  family_name: Input[str]
  email: Input[str]
  phone: Optional[Input[str]]
  picture: Optional[Input[str]]
  role: Input[str]
  def __init__(self, given_name, family_name, email, phone=None, picture=None, role="ReadOnly"):
    self.given_name = given_name
    self.family_name = family_name
    self.email = email
    self.phone = phone
    self.picture = picture
    self.role = role

class FivetranUserProvider(ResourceProvider):
  def _auth(self):
    return HTTPBasicAuth("my-key", "my-secret")

  def create(self, props):
    payload = {
      "given_name": props["given_name"],
      "family_name": props["family_name"],
      "email": props["email"],
      "phone": props["phone"] if "phone" in props else None,
      "picture": props["picture"] if "picture" in props else None,
      "role": props["role"]
    }

    url = "https://api.fivetran.com/v1/users"
    response = requests.post(url=url,auth=self._auth(),json=payload).json()

    return CreateResult(response["data"]["id"], {**props, **response.raw_data})

class FivetranUser(Resource):
  given_name: Output[str]
  family_name: Output[str]
  email: Output[str]
  phone: Output[str]
  picture: Output[str]
  role: Output[str]

  def __init__(self, name, args: FivetranUserArgs, opts = None):
    full_args = {'name': None, 'given_name':None, 'family_name':None, 'email':None, 'phone':None, 'picture':None, 'role':None, **vars(args)}
    super().__init__(FivetranUserProvider(), name, full_args, opts)
```

This is called by code in **main**.py:

```
from fivetran_pulumi import FivetranUser as User, FivetranUserArgs as UserArgs
import json
import pulumi
import pulumi_aws as aws

stack = pulumi.get_stack()
slack_secret = aws.secretsmanager.get_secret_version("eda/slack").secret_string
slack_email = json.loads(slack_secret)["monitoring-channel-email"]

slack_bot_user = User(
  stack + "-slack-bot",
  UserArgs(
    given_name = 'slack',
    family_name = 'bot',
    email = slack_email,
    role = "ReadOnly"))
```

I execute this using `pulumi up`.

I'm running:

- Pulumi 3.1.0
- Python 3.9.2
- Powershell 7.1.3
- Windows 10 Pro

Comment: This seems like it was probably a problem with Pulumi at the time, can you confirm whether this is the case?